# How to right join a date table in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have done RIGHT JOINS in the past with no problems.  However, for some reason now, I am not able successfully join a date table on the date field.  In summary, I have two tables.  The first table has one date column and a couple more non-date columns.  Then I have a date table, which just has two date columns.

I initialize this date table by inserting into it first of month dates for 13 consecutive months.  But my other table only has 9 months of data.

So table A looks like:

```
col_A    col_B     col_C
-----    ------    -------
sfds     jkjlj     7-1-2009
rewr     sfsfsd    5-1-2009
xcxvg    sdfsfk    4-1-2009
...
```

But table B looks like:

```
StartDate   EndDate
---------   ---------
7-1-2009    7-31-2009
6-1-2009    6-30-2009
5-1-2009    5-31-2009
...
```

But when I right join table B onto A like so:

```
    SELECT *
      FROM TABLE_A A
RIGHT JOIN TABLE_B B ON A.COL_C = B.StartDate
```

I expect to get 12 months of data since Table_B has 13 months/records.  However, instead I am only getting 9 months total.  Does anybody understand why this would be?  And other things I might try to achieve the same result?

My main goal is to make Table_A include every month for past 13 months, even if there are null values.  Right now though, it just includes 9 months since there no records for the other 4 months.

Comment: TSQL for Sybase or SQL Server?  Version would help too

Comment: You sure the full version doesn't have a where clause?

Comment: Can you give us all data in both tables *and* the actual query please? If there are 13 rows in B you'd get 13 rows out unless you've filtered them out with a WHERE or something

Comment: I'm thinking something is confused. If you do SELECT * FROM TABLE_B do you actually get 13 rows?

Answer (score 8):

Joining on date columns can be problematic if there is a time portion to the dates (and there often is!).

It's safer to use `DATEPART()` or `CONVERT()` (or other date functions) to extract just the date portion but this will probably exclude using indexes.

one way is to use:

```
DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, DateColumn), 0)
```

i.e.

```
SELECT *      
FROM TABLE_A A
RIGHT JOIN TABLE_B B ON 
   DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, A.COL_C), 0) = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, B.StartDate), 0)
```

There is also this form:

```
CAST(FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)
```

but I prefer the former.

Comment: Thanks, you just reminded me.  The date column in Table_A is actually a CASTed date, where it casts the date into the first day of that month, but it still remains a date datatype.  Thanks for the tips though.  I am not at my work computer now, but I will try this tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: Even if they didn't match he should have the records since it is an outer join.

Comment: Thanks Mitch, but I actually need the first day of month from Table_A.  And your code just gives me that same day.  How would I do this for first day of month?

Comment: thanks i modified my description.  Can u look?  still < 13 months.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried this and got all months, columns col_A, col_B and col_C being null where there wasn't a match.  Are you sure all your dates are there and there isn't a where clause affecting this?

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_A A

sfds    jkjlj   2009-07-01 00:00:00.000


SELECT *
FROM TABLE_B B

2009-07-01 00:00:00.000 2009-07-31 00:00:00.000
2009-06-01 00:00:00.000 2009-06-30 00:00:00.000
2009-05-01 00:00:00.000 2009-05-31 00:00:00.000


SELECT *
FROM TABLE_A A
RIGHT JOIN TABLE_B B ON A.COL_C = B.StartDate

sfds    jkjlj   2009-07-01 00:00:00.000 2009-07-01 00:00:00.000 2009-07-31 00:00:00.000
NULL    NULL    NULL    2009-06-01 00:00:00.000 2009-06-30 00:00:00.000
NULL    NULL    NULL    2009-05-01 00:00:00.000 2009-05-31 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: thanks i modified my description.  Can u look?  still < 13 months.  i removed the where clause in 2nd insert.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do when joining on dates is to convert them to integers first since joining on dates (1) often gives unexpected results, and (2) it is slow.

I would do the join like so:

```
Select * 
From
TABLE_A A 
Right Join 
TABLE_B B 
On 
((Year(A.COL_C)*10000) + (Month(A.COL_C)*100) + Day(A.COL_C)) = ((Year(B.StartDate)*10000) + (Month(B.StartDate)*100) + Day(B.StartDate))
```

However it seems you really want to join the year and month since the date on Table_A is always the 1st.
I would do that like so:

```
Select * 
From
TABLE_A A 
Right Join 
TABLE_B B 
On 
((Year(A.COL_C)*100) + Month(A.COL_C)) = ((Year(B.StartDate)*100) + Month(B.StartDate))
```

Hope this helps.